# PHP: how to roughly emulate sys_getloadavg()

Tags: php, unix, server

I am trying to resize and optimize about 1 million huge pictures on a **live server**. And although it is not a shared server my provider ([domainfactory](http://www.df.eu)) does not support any of the load checks I am aware of:

- PHPs *sys_getloadavg()* returns `array("0.00", "0.00", "0.00")`
- Unix's *top* will return "load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00"
- The same applies to Unix's *uptime* command

Now I am looking for a way to get a comparable result. Even if it means...

1. ... that I have to put more load on the server (e.g. by dummy CPU jobs) and
2. ... that the results are only rough estimates.

Can this be done? And if so: how?

Comment: Would you consider something like NewRelic to tell you what kind of load your machine is under? Might be a bit much just for a single task but its handy to have regardless.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me there. Right now I still think that might be a overhead. Unfortunatly I have some time constraints right now... :-/